# Function-style template syntax

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic

I'm trying to write a rather simple class that takes a function, some arguments, and can execute the function with the arguments at a later time.

Currently, this is my code:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
class Delayed
{
public:
    using FunctionT = std::function<R(Args...)>;

    Delayed(FunctionT func, Args... args) : func(func), args(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {

    }

private:
    FunctionT func;
    std::tuple<Args...> args;
};

int main()
{
    std::function<double(double)> doubleMe = [](double x) { return x * 2.0; };

    //Works
    Delayed<double, double> delayed1(doubleMe, 2.0);

    //Doesn't work
    Delayed<double(double)> delayed2(doubleMe, 2.0);
}
```

The problem is that when I pass `double(double)` as an argument, instead of `R` being `double` and `Args` being `double`, it passes `double(double)` to `R` and nothing to `Args`.

[According to cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), the template arguments for `std::function` is `template< class R, class... Args >`. So if I give it `A(B,C)`, it will pass `A` for the argument `R` and `B,C` for the variadic argument `Args`. But when I pass that to my class it passes `A(B,C)` for `R`  and passes nothing for the variadic argument `Args`.

How is this function syntax supposed to be used and why does it work for `std::function` but not my class?

Comment: Because they are written differently. Use partial specialization on function types

Comment: `auto delayed = std::bind(doubleMe, 2.);` followed by `delayed()` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I considered that and while it would work it is more convenient for me to have a class similar to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So if I give it `A(B,C)`, it will pass `A` for the argument `R` and `B,C` for the variadic argument `Args`.

Yes, but not for the reasons you think. If you look closely, you'll see that `std::function` partially specializes for any function type:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
class function<R(Args...)>;
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can imagine this as very primitive pattern matching. If you instantiate `function` with `int(int, double)`, then it makes sense that `R` is `int`, and `Args` is `int, double`. If a (partial) specialization is a better match than the catch-all generic primary template, then it is chosen, which is what happens here.

Remember: `double(double)` is a type, it's a function. There aren't any special rules involving it. So, in your case, you would do this:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
class Delayed<R(Args...)> : public Delayed<R, Args...> {
  //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  //       partially specialize to decompose function types

  // We need to inherit constructors (only).
  using Delayed<R, Args...>::Delayed;
};
```

Hope it clears up the confusion.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for answering!